# New users can't log in. Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, authentication, django-class-based-views

I'm using a view to create new users in Django. And then I have another view to log them in.

But when I create a user, and I try to log in with authenticate(username=username_post, password=password_post), I get None, so it displays in the template 'Wrong username or password.'.

In my database, I see new registers every time I create a new user. However, as the password is encrypted, I can't say if the problem is the login view, or the register view.

However, the super user that I created through the command line after I first installed django, is able to login with no problem, so that makes me thing that the problem is when I create the user.

These are my Login and Register views:

```
class Login(View):
    form = LoginForm()
    message = None
    template = 'settings/blog_login.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            return redirect('settings:index')
        return render(request, self.template, self.get_context())

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        username_post = request.POST['username']
        password_post = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username_post, password=password_post)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('settings:index')
        else:
            self.message = 'Wrong username or password.'
            return render(request, self.template, self.get_context())

    def get_context(self):
        return {'form': self.form, 'message': self.message}


class Register(CreateView):
    success_url = reverse_lazy('settings:login')
    model = User
    template_name = 'settings/blog_register.html'
    form_class = RegisterForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.set_password(self.object.password)
        self.object.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

And these are my forms:

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=20, label='Username')
    password = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput())


class RegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=20, label='Username')
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput(),
                                error_messages={'required': 'Required field.',
                                                'unique': 'Username already used.',
                                                'invalid': 'Not valid username.'})
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Retype password', widget=forms.PasswordInput(),
                                error_messages={'required': 'Required field.'})
    email = forms.EmailField(error_messages={'required': 'Required field.',
                                             'invalid': 'Invalid email.'})

    def clean(self):
        clean_data = super(RegisterForm, self).clean()
        password1 = clean_data.get('password1')
        password2 = clean_data.get('password2')
        if password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Passwords are different.')
        return self.cleaned_data

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
        if email and User.objects.filter(email=email).exclude(
                username=username).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError('Email already used.')
        return email

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'password1', 'password2', 'email')
```

Please, let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a field called 'password' in your form - you just have 'password1' and 'password2' -  so nothing is saved to the model object's actual password field. So, when you do `self.object.set_password(self.object.password)`, you're actually setting a blank password.

Instead, you should get the value from your form's password1 field:

```
self.object.set_password(self.form.cleaned_data['password1'])
```

Comment: You are right, I wouldn't have noticed if it wasn't for your help. I just used  `form.cleaned_data['password1']` without `self`. And now its working perfectly